# angular2-toaster info issus

Tags: angular, angular2-toaster

in fact, I use these toaster service in angular, when I display a toast info it displays two icons on the left.

[image]

my question: how can I eliminate the icon displayed at the top left?

```
    this.toasterService.pop('info',
    'Désolé, vous n\'êtes pas autorisé à accéder à cette page!',
    'Cette notification signifie simplement qu’il y a un réglage de rôle qui vous bloque à accéder à une certaine zone.');
```

this is my html generated by this service:

```
`<div class="toast ng-tns-c1-0 toast-info ng-trigger ng-trigger-toastState ng-star-inserted" toastcomp="" ng-reflect-klass="toast" ng-reflect-ng-class="toast-info" ng-reflect-toast="[object Object]" ng-reflect-icon-class="icon-info" ng-reflect-title-class="toast-title" ng-reflect-message-class="toast-message" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
    <i class="toaster-icon icon-info" ng-reflect-klass="toaster-icon" ng-reflect-ng-class="icon-info"></i>
    <div class="toast-content">
        <div class="toast-title" ng-reflect-ng-class="toast-title">Désolé ...</div>
        <div class="toast-message" ng-reflect-ng-class="toast-message" ng-reflect-ng-switch="0"><div class="ng-star-inserted" style=""> Cette ...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

Comment: Show the html code.

Comment: @aepifano done :)

Comment: Not the generated html, the source html. :D